# Remote desktop shows horizonal scroll bar when maximized even there are space for it on local PC

Tags: windows, display, remote-desktop, scrolling

Resolution of local display is 1920 x 1080, and the display of remote desktop is set to
1440 x 1050. When maximize the window of remote desktop, both vertical and horizontal scroll bar showed.

Horizontal scroll bar should not be showed because there is plenty of space on
local display (1920 is far larger than 1440). And when not maximized, resize the remote desktop window to a wider size cause horizontal scroll bar to disappear.

Below is the picture of scroll bars when maximized.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When resizing the remote desktop window, I accidentally cause those scroll bars to disappear. But it not always worked. So I tried many times and find the trick to make those scroll bars disappear.

1. Move the title bar to the top of desktop of local PC. Note do not trigger the maximize action.
2. Resize the remote desktop window by dragging the bottom-right corner towards bottom-right, until both vertical and horizontal scroll bars disappear.
3. Release the mouse, then both vertical and horizontal scroll bars reappear. Don't worry, move the remote desktop window by dragging the title bar and immediately releasing it. Then both vertical and horizontal scroll bars disappear again, it will remain this status when you move or minimize remote desktop window.

[image]

Comment: Although it solve my problem, but I not know why.

Comment: The resolution of your desktop exceeded the size of the window of the application, thus you were being provided the ability, to view the entire desktop.  This explanation is proven by the fact, you solved it, by expanding the size of the window.

Comment: The problem is why there is horizontal scroll bar when maximized, while when not maximized there is not. Maybe maximization window do something wrong in this situation.

Comment: The remote desktop client window clearly is NOT maximized.  If it was then the desktop behind the window could not be seen.

Comment: You are right, it is not maximized in normal way. But that is what happened when I press 'maximize' button of remote desktop client window. I guess maximization of a remote desktop client window is not the same as other application, it will take as much space as the display size in the client setting instead of all the space of local desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and when I clicked on the top bar (Where you hid your computer name), and choose full screen, it maximized and filled the screen.
I hope this helps someone.